# How does deletion-contraction affect chromatic number? Can it increase chromatic number?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

**Question:** In graph theory, contracting an edge or deleting an edge are *basic* operations in many topics such as [graph minors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) or [Wagner's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner's_theorem) on planar graphs. And I'm interested in how these operations affect [chromatic number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChromaticNumber.html), which is the smallest number of colors needed to color the vertices of a graph so that adjacent vertices have different colors.

**Maybe... :** My guess is that these operation *never* increases the chromatic number of any graph because, roughly speaking, contraction-deletion makes a graph 'less complicated'. (Excuse my sloppy expression.) For example, a planar graph is 4-colorable even after deletion-contraction operations because they preserve planairty.

**Maybe not... :** But pondering about [Braess's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braess's_paradox), which states that adding a route can cause overall traffic delays to worsen, I'm guessing this question may not be trivial at all and my intuition about deletion-contraction may be wrong.

---

- Is my question about chromatic number under deletion-contraction trivially true?
- If not, is there any paper about this topic?
- Is my *conjecture* true in a restricted setting, such as "A deletion-contraction operation in a planar graph never increases the chromatic number"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is trivially false. Contracting an edge in an even cycle increases the chromatic number. Deleting edges never increase the chromatic number however, a coloring stays a coloring after deleting an edge.

Comment: Arghhh, you're right.